# The Bootstrap modal in React js is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am following this tutorial (https://www.bigbinary.com/videos/keep-up-with-reactjs/creating-a-bootstrap-modal-in-react-js)

to create a modal, but I have this problem.
[image]

A gray layer will not let me use the modal. I already checked the css file but I do not know where I am doing wrong.

Please help me

this is my code:

Login.js

```js
import React, { Component,PropTypes } from 'react';


class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
          <div>
  <button type="button" id='ingresar' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Ingresar
  </button>

  <div className="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span className="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 className="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
          </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem should lie with you css. change the z-index of the modal to some higher value.

Comment: but not working change the z index :(

Comment: Hello @EmmanuelGarciaMartinez was problem solved , please answer solution if solved

Comment: @Becauseihatemyself I had to build my own modal, I liked it a lot because I have more control of the aspect

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I found out that my problem is related to the `fade` class. As soon as I removed it my problem was solved.

Comment: really? I had to remove the modal, but I will try to do what you tell me thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use modals in React, you need to install the react-bootstrap bootstrap package.

```
npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

The procedure after installing the package is as follows:

```
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const App = () => {
   return (
     <Modal show={true}>
       <Modal.Header>Hi</Modal.Header>
       <Modal.Body>asdfasdf</Modal.Body>
       <Modal.Footer>This is the footer</Modal.Footer>
     </Modal>
   );
};
```